# ¿Cómo pedir que mi código sea incorporado a un repositorio de control de versiones de software?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, informática

La expresión habitual en inglés para pedir que mi código sea incorporado a un repositorio de control de versiones de software es "pull request".
Pero "Peticion de estirar/traer/jalar" suena raro. Y tampoco transmite el concepto necesario: una solicitud de que el trabajo de programación que he hecho y ofrezco sea integrado con un código ya existente mediante el uso de una herramienta de control de versiones.

Lo mejor que se me ocurre es "petición de integración".

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]! La propuesta que haces me parece bien. A mí de momento se me ocurre "solicitud de incorporación".

Answer (score 5):

El Visual Studio 2015 se integra con repositorios Git, y la operación de "push" la traduce como "insertar". Aunque es la traducción del término opuesto a "pull", en realidad todo depende del punto de vista. Desde el punto de vista del que ha escrito el nuevo código cuya aceptación se desea conseguir, lo que se espera es que su "push" sea aceptado (haciendo un "pull" desde la otra parte). Por tanto

> **Solicitud de inserción**

no me sonaría mal, ya que hablamos de eso, de conseguir que el código sea insertado en el repositorio, aunque se use la traducción de la operación opuesta (la traducción de "pull" en Visual Studio es "extraer", y la verdad es que "solicitud de extracción" no queda nada bien).

Answer (score 4):

No sé vosotros pero yo nunca he oído nada diferente de *pull request* y casi todos los manuales que encuentro en castellano utilizan el término inglés. Sin embargo, considero muy sano intentar una traducción que dé claridad al término, especialmente para esta tecnología que tiene una curva de aprendizaje un poco complicada y que se presta a equívocos.

De ahí que [la sugerencia de Carlos Alejo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/19645/1674) me parezca muy acertada y entendible.

Puestos a sugerir, veo que en la documentación oficial de Git, sección [5.2 Git en entornos distribuidos - Contribuyendo a un proyecto](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Git-en-entornos-distribuidos-Contribuyendo-a-un-proyecto) mencionan:

> Tras enviar (push) tu trabajo a tu copia bifurcada (fork), has de notificarselo al gestor del proyecto. Normalmente se suele hacer a través de una *solicitud de recuperación/integración* (pull request).

*Recuperación* me parece poco adecuado, puesto que sugiere una pérdida previa. Por tanto, **solicitud de integración** sería mi propuesta. A *integración* le veo la bondad de proyectar la imagen de las ramas o flujos diferentes de código. Por otra parte, le veo la parte mala de usar el verbo *integrar*, muy usado en estos ámbitos en conceptos como la [*integración continua*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integraci%C3%B3n_continua), que afecta a una capa algo más alta en el sistema de trabajo.

Comment: +1 por dar una buena referencia para este caso, pero prefiero la opción propuesta por @Carlos Alejo porque la palabra *inserción* no tiene ese significado equívoco que señalas para *integración*.